# terraform import aws_vpc.main vpc-0ea21234

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I import an existing vpc into terraform I get the following error when running my terraform script.

Error: error deleting EC2 VPC (vpc-0ea21234): DependencyViolation: The vpc 'vpc-0ea21234' has dependencies and cannot be deleted.
status code: 400, request id: 4630706a-5378-4e72-a3df-b58c8c7fd09b

Why is it trying to delete the VPC? How can I make it use the VPC? I'll post the main file I used to make the import and the import command below.

import command (this succeeds)

`terraform import aws_vpc.main vpc-0ea21234`

main file

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-gov-west-1"
  profile = "int-pipe"
}

# terraform import aws_vpc.main vpc-0ea21234
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  name                 = "cred-int-pipeline-vpc"
  cidr                 = "10.25.0.0/25"
}

# terraform import aws_subnet.main subnet-030de2345
resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  vpc_id = "vpc-0ea21234"
  name = "cred-int-pipeline-subnet-d-az2"
  cidr = "10.25.0.96/27"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem here? The import works but the issue is?

Comment: It would be super helpful to view the `plan` output here.

Comment: You are not giving us the whole picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have differences between what you have in your terraform configuration file and the resource you imported.
Run `terraform plan`, it will show you exactly what the differences are and the reason why it must be deleted/re-created.

After that, either manually change the resource in AWS or in your configuration file, if both existing resource and file match configuration, than delete and re-create won't be triggered.